# Allow checkbox to be disabled in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-browser

So I am working on cross-browser code right now.  I have checkboxes, that disable after certain functions are called, in IE but not in Firefox & Chrome.

I looked into the code and I see that when rendered in Firefox, the disabled tag is placed on the `td` which is why it works in IE and not the other browsers.

Is there a way in asp.net to disable the cell or checkbox and have it render properly in Firefox, Chrome, etc?

Here is my function where enabled = false

```
protected void FilterCheckBox(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableCommandCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (ExecContractGridView != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ExecContractGridView.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "UnionExecutedBy") != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExecContractGridView.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "UnionExecutedBy").ToString()))
                {
                    e.Cell.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationLog.Exception(this, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this properly you want to find the checkbox control and set `disabled = "disabled"`.

You can do so on the client side using JavaScript or a library like jQuery.  Or, in your code above, once you have `e.Cell` you can locate the `CheckBox` control and set it to `Enabled = false`.

To further clarify, `e.Cell` contains a `CheckBox` control as one of its child controls. So you could do:

```
var control = e.Cell.FindControl("SomeCheckBoxControl") as CheckBox;
if (control != null)
    control.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% following..  could you explain?

Comment: Thank you, now to just find the checkbox name..  I inherited this code and on my design view, I only see a gridview and when I inspect the element in Chrome, it gives me a massive name that switches each row

Comment: You need to look at the ASPX code to determine what the control is called.  Or if you're looking at the element in Chrome, try using just the end of the mangled name. It would be the final text after the last `$` character.

Comment: my input's have ID's of ctl00_middleContent_ExecContractGridView_DXSelBtn##    And no name

Comment: You'll need to name it in the ASPX then.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Yuck.  I see that this was created using ASP DevExpress so I will have to look into this some more...  because the checkboxes arent even listed in the .aspx file